# Node-sqlite3 sorting

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I'm programming a website to search in a sqlite database. I'm using node-sqlite3 in my backend, this is my code.

```js
let query = `SELECT * FROM "main"."SPTOT" WHERE lower("Country") LIKE 'australia' ESCAPE '\\' ORDER BY Country, Operator, "Basic Type", Serial, Date`;
  db.all(query, (err, rows) => {    
    if (err) throw err;
    res.json({
      rows: rows,
      query: query
    });
  });
```

The result is sorted by date, but it should sort by Country, Operator, BasicType, Serial and then Date.

When I'm using [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/) with the exact same query, the results are sorted like they should be.

**From node-sqlite3**
[image]

**From DB Browser**
[image]

I don't know if this is an issue from node-sqlite3 or something else. If this is an issue in node-sqlite3, is there another way to sort te results how I want to in javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I created a sorting function to sort it right after running the query and getting the results. I reported this issue to the github repository.
This is the sorting function.

```js
function sort(array, keysInObj) {
  let elements = keysInObj.reverse();
  for (let e of elements) {
    array.sort((a, b) => `${a[e]}`.localeCompare(b[e]));
  }
  return array;
}
```

This is now my code.

```js
let query = `SELECT * FROM "main"."SPTOT" WHERE lower("Country") LIKE 'australia' ESCAPE '\\' ORDER BY Country, Operator, "Basic Type", Serial, Date`;
db.all(query, (err, rows) => {    
  if (err) throw err;
  rows = sort(rows, ["Country", "Operator", "Basic Type", "Serial", "Date"]);
  res.json({
    rows: rows,
    query: query
  });
});
```